# C# Out of memory exception memory on 32bit

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, memory-management, memory-leaks

Hello stack overflow community.

I currently have a performance problem with one of my biggest customers. Our WCF server grows linearly until it crashes.

We have already identified several problems with memory leak and unmanaged object that was not collected properly.

During our research we determined that there are several types of memory.

- Virtual memory
- Working set memory
- Private bytes

My question is, what type of memory make our server crash?
What is the limit of a 32-bit process for each type of memory?

This is a WCF application in 4.5 standard framework. Which in most cases run on 32 bit machines but can also run on 32 bit windows. (I have seen that a 32 bit application does not allocate the same amount of memory on a 32 or 64 bit windows)

We want to develop a logger that can warn if a process reaches its maximum memory allocation and if it can make it crash.

Thanks to all,
Have a nice day !

Comment: This is a very hard question to answer. For example, you can run out of memory for the [Large Object Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) due to fragmentation, even if there's still plenty of other memory available.

Comment: Thanks for answering, we found that was this line which in cause. AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run); And we recently investigate on other memory leak but with less success. LOH was an option but i'm not sure how it works and we can show which memory is in default